# How save or update single inputText field using ajax listener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I spent already more time as is good about some saving or updating issue in inputtext field, i go right to the point:
i have basic single input text with some basic attributtes

> `<h:inputText id="name" value="#{salesController.selectedSalesName}" />`

here is a getter for inputText value

```
public String getSelectedSalesName(){
    for(DealerListView dealer : dealerList){
        if(dealer.getDealerId() == getSelectedDealerId()){
            return dealer.getName();
        }
    }
    return "";  
}
```

nested in there i use ajax tag

```
<f:ajax event="change" render="name" listener="#{salesController.updateSelectedSalesName()}" />
```

a here is back bean method for updating a input text field

```
public void updateSelectedSalesName() {     

        DealerData dealDat = BeanFactory.getHotelDAOService(DealerData.class).findOne(selectedDealerId);
        dealDat.setName(name);
        BeanFactory.getHotelDAOService(DealerData.class).update(dealDat);     
}
```

whole result of this is stack trace which say

> value="#{salesController.selectedSalesName}": Property 'selectedSalesName' not writable on type sk.hotel.web.controller.SalesController

I know that something changes is need for that getter method but try some combinations without result which make corect update of value to database.

(I dont use any commands buttons for submit,update only response on pressing Enter in that inputText field.)
I want some guide how can be modified this save/update process whether on back-bean or jsf layout
or maybe someone solved similar situation already,and can share his solution.

Thanks all of you for advice posts.
Regards and nice day

Comment: 1. `<h:inputText>` value attribute binding needs **both setter and getter** of the bean's property and the former should cause the prblems you face. 2. You will face performance problems, as the getter may be called many times and the way you wrote it is resource-consuming (alternative: use other String property that you evaluate in `Constructor` / `@PostConstruct` method / `preRenderView` event. 3. Ajax listener must be of the following type `public void ajaxListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)`, so change your method declaration in your bean.

Comment: thank you for post,also for these advices,yes before i thinking about binding both od setter/getter,but this was just light overview,not go into very deeply about this,i try to modified based on this my code,i see how far i get:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add a field:

```
  String selectedSalesName;
```

Add a setter and setter:

```
  public String getSelectedSalesName() {
     return selectedSalesName;
  }
  public void setSelectedSalesName(String selectedSalesName) {
     this.selectedSalesName = selectedSalesName;
  }
```

Add a ajaxListener(AjaxBehaviurEvent event) to create a new Dealer or Update current Dealer

```
  public void ajaxListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
     Dao dao = BeanFactory.getHotelDAOService(DealerData.class)
     if (selectedDealerId == null) {
        DealarData dealerData= new DealerData();
        dealerDate.setName(getSelectedSalesName());
        dao.add(dealerData);
        setDealer(dealerData);
     } else {
        DealerData dealDat = dao.findOne(selectedDealerId);
        dealDat.setName(name);
        dao.update(dealDat);
     }
  }
```

A setter to the current dealer

```
  int selectedDealerId;
  public void setDealer(DealerData dealer) {
        selectedDealerId = dealer.getId();
        selectedSalesName = dealer.getName();
  }
```

And the xhtml page:

```
  <h:inputText value="#{salesController.selectedSalesName}" id="idSalesInput">
        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{salesController.ajaxListener}" 
               execute="idSalesInput"/>
  </h:inputText>
```

Change "keyup" for the event you want to listen.

When you press a key, the listener is called, and the value of idSalesInput is submitted (the setSelectedSalesName() method is called here, for this reason you got the Property 'selectedSalesName' not writable exception),and the listener create or update a new DealerData.

Have a nice Day and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very nice presentation which show how provide submiting value in Jsf,something like this i want found but without result,ok i made some modifications based on this and let you know how is going,regards

Comment: Do you want to scare the database with so many operations (*keyup*)? It is **bad practice**. Change placeholders instead.

Comment: @skuntsel i think the best event to listen is "onblur", can you specify (or a link) what is a PlaceHolder please?

Comment: Placeholder is simply a blank class instance that is used to store data during user interaction with the object. It means that no business actions are triggered during interaction with the object, but are later confirmed via action methods. This way, for example, setName method will literally set name in a placeholder, while save (etc.) methods will trigger database manipulation with the *stored placeholder*.

Comment: @AVolpe  i tried your solution,i get a bit forward with this, and show me this stacktrace: 

com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
listener="#{salesController.ajaxListener}": java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke
i noticed here about "InvokeApplicationPhase" so this means my listener cant get into a RenderResponse phase?is due to NullPointerException?

Comment: @Maston can you paste your StackTrace in webpage like pastebin.com please, i think the problem is in the listener..

Comment: @AVolpe ok i pasted it,you look at that there? also i think there must be something to modify in that listener, and about dealDat.setName(name) can be "name" attribute replaced with "selectedSalesName" from setter method,maybe this property contain new value what i type in input field for update i guess.

Comment: @Maston yo need to paste, submit and copy the url and paste here!. You are using a IDE that support debug?.. you can debut the listener to see what happends.

Comment: @AVolpe aha ok,please here is that mentioned stacktrace http://pastebin.com/GXpJf75V   ,about debuging i havent experience yet,but is a good idea try debug listener i kept this as one of possible option to solved this, but so far still dont know why save/update from listener not proceed.but so far i try to found why is compliance about InvokeAplicationPhase from stacktrace and dont skip to RenderResponsePhase

Comment: hi @Maston the line 187 of your code has a null refence, i dont know what line is it, but the code works well, you only need to change the logic to store the data, try comment the body of ajaxListener(event) and see how dont throw any exception, you can mail me (see my profile for my email adress) and i can explain better the problem and in spanish!. My english is so bad.

Comment: @AVolpe Ok thanks for your time to solved this, you give me some useful ideas what i dont try before,becasue also  try modified that Listener method without success. ok if i found something based on you ideas or my attempts than better be continue on mail communications, and dont worry about english i have same feelings about my english:)

Comment: @AVolpe Hi, yes you have right line 187 is null reference, is this line "dealer.setName(selectedDealerName);" line 188 is update line "BeanFactory.getHotelDAOService(DealerData.class).update(dealDat);" how can be set "selectedDealerName" parameter to change form null reference? and please give me your mail i didnt find in your profile,thank you,

Comment: i see your variable of type DealerData is dealDat, change the line 187 for "dealDat.setName(selectedDealerName)" and try. my mail is arturovolpe@gmail!.

Comment: ok thanks,i will continue via mail,i send you there  this listener method and setter method and i try explain where i think is a problem and then you mail me back what you think about it, Thanks so far

Answer (score 1):

Binding value in your `inputText` is two way, when it is rendered than getter is called to calculate value, when it is submited (like in your AJAX event) setter is called for that property to set value in your backing bean. So JSF tries to call `setSelectedSalesName(String value)`. JSF can't write your property, which means can't call setter.

**See also:**

- [AJAX listener not being fired for  inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053370/ajax-listener-not-being-fired-for-pselectbooleanbutton-inside-pdatalist/15054756#15054756)